# How to dynamically add Image to dynamically created ImageView

Tags: android, imageview, layout-inflater

I'm trying to dynamically add an Image to a dynamically created ImageView. 
The app crashes as soon as I select an Image. I tried it with a non-dynamiclly created view and it worked fine. I'm not sure where my problem is.

I've inflated the layout containing the ImageView, should I inflate the ImageView also? I'm not sure where my problem is. This is my main class.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

int clickCounterIndex = 0;
LinearLayout picsLayout;
LayoutInflater inflater;
View picItem;

Intent intentForPic;
int RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE = 1;
ImageView pic;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    intentForPic = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    pic = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.picImageView);

    picsLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.picsLayout);
    inflater = (LayoutInflater)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

}

public void addStuff(View view) {

    intentForPic = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    intentForPic.setType("image/*");
    startActivityForResult(intentForPic, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);

    picItem = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_layout, picsLayout, false);
    picsLayout.addView(picItem, clickCounterIndex);
    clickCounterIndex++;

}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if(requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK){
        Uri imageUri = data.getData();
        pic.setImageURI(imageUri);

    }
}
}
```

Main layout file.

```
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/picsLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:gravity="top"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<Button
    android:text="click me!"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:onClick="addStuff"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

The dynamically added layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="200dp"
tools:context="com.example.k0k0.thenextsnapchat.imageuploaddemo.MainActivity">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/picImageView"
    android:layout_width="90dp"
    android:layout_height="90dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_popup_disk_full"/>

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/picUploadProgressBar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
    android:progress="100"/>

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/xImageButton"
    android:src="@android:drawable/btn_minus"
    android:layout_width="24dp"
    android:layout_height="24dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="38dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="38dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your `ImageView` is part of you dynamically created view. So you have to hold a refrence to it like this:

```
picItem = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_layout, picsLayout, false);

pic = (ImageView) picItem.findViewById(R.id.picImageView);

picsLayout.addView(picItem, clickCounterIndex);
clickCounterIndex++;
```

Comment: This works but only the first time. When I try to add more items it doesn't display an Image anymore. Why do you think that is?

Comment: because you only have a single `ImageView` in your layout. If you dont know the amount of images there is you should go with a `ListView` or `RecyclerView`

Comment: I did try it with a <code>ListView</code> but it only worked when I'd set a fixed height of the <code>ListView</code>. How would you tackle that sort of problem? What do you think might've caused it?